# Formatting floats with decimal dots and limited decimal part in Django templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-1.8

I know I can limit the number of decimals in a float by using the filter `floatformat:2` which output a localized float and also I know the filter `stringformat:"f"` which outputs a dotted float like **1.54** instead of a localized comma float like **1,54**.

For instance, if the original float is **1.54233** I would like to print **1.54** and not **1,54** or **1.54233**. Can this be achieved without the need of a custom filter?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. `floatformat` is not a custom filter, why not use it?

Comment: @ShangWang because `floatformat` returns a localized float using commas instead of points (or dots)

Comment: you can change the locale in a block with some tags

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/formatting/#localize

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just use the localize/unlocalize format separator

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/formatting/#std:templatefilter-localize

> For example:
>
> `{% load l10n %}`
>
> `{{ value|localize }}`
>
> To disable localization on a single value, use unlocalize. To control
>   localization over a large section of a template, use the localize
>   template tag. unlocalize¶
>
> Forces a single value to be printed without localization.
>
> For example:
>
> `{% load l10n %}`
>
> `{{ value|unlocalize }}`
>
> To force localization of a single value, use localize. To control
>   localization over a large section of a template, use the localize
>   template tag.

edit:

see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates

```
{% load i18n %}

{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
<!-- Current language: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} -->
<p>{% trans "Welcome to our page" %}</p>

{% language 'en' %}
    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    <!-- Current language: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} -->
    <p>{% trans "Welcome to our page" %}</p>
{% endlanguage %}
```

you can switch languages to force the display if localize/unlocalize does not work

Comment: can I use this after a `floatformat` filter? like `{{ val|floaformat:2|unlocalize}}` ?

Comment: for some reason it is not working, I mean the floats are still being printed with a comma as decimal separator even using the `localize off` I think the `floatfomat` filter is not considering it

Comment: It's weird, I had to disable I10N for the commas to stop showing but the `unlocalize` didn't worked

Comment: Testing a little bit more I confirmed that `floatformat` indeed Ignores the `unlocalize` filter and the `localize off` tag, so what to do there?

Comment: specify a custom separator( see links above) and file a bug report at django on github

Comment: Using ``floatformat`` with ``language`` still works, so you can do ``{% language 'en'%}{{ value|floatformat:'1' }}{% endlanguage %}`` to get an "unlocalized" value. if you need a real number

Answer (score 23):

Note, that localization (and therefore the [`unlocalize` filter and `localize` tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#controlling-localization-in-templates)) have **NO** effect on the output of [`floatformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat)! At the time of writing there is an [open issue about better documentation](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30086).

While switching the language to "en" is a workaround, it is not necessary to achieve (a) always using a dot and (b) limiting the number of decimals and in my opinion taking advantage of a language feature side-effect is less than ideal.

To properly format a float with Django template filters independent of localization you *can* use [`stringformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat)! [Printf-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) does not only accept a single conversion (like `"f"`), but several optional parameters like "precision". See the linked Python docs for details.

To format your float **1.54233** as **1.54** simply use:

```
{{ float_value|stringformat:".2f" }}
```